# CMS GC very long pause

Tags: java, garbage-collection

Here are my some GC logs. If you see most of the real time is less then the user time as I am application seems to be using multiple threads for GC. but one case, I see the real and user are same. Why is that

```
2020-05-15T09:10:30.389+0000: 545173.557: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.438/1.438 secs] [Times: user=19.06 sys=2.35, real=1.44 secs] 
2020-05-15T09:10:31.474+0000: 545174.642: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 0.956/1.043 secs] [Times: user=5.56 sys=2.20, real=1.04 secs] 
2020-05-15T10:50:30.935+0000: 551174.102: [GC (Allocation Failure) 2020-05-15T10:50:30.935+0000: 551174.102: [ParNew (promotion failed): 2342575K->2343419K(2530368K), 0.5566294 secs]2020-05-15T10:50:31.491+0000: 551174.658: [CMS: 11401717K->2753238K(13965760K), 12.4962964 secs] 13743114K->2753238K(16496128K), [Metaspace: 40012K->40012K(1085440K)], 13.0530955 secs] [Times: user=13.89 sys=0.00, real=13.06 secs] 
2020-05-15T12:43:00.260+0000: 557923.427: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.298/1.298 secs] [Times: user=17.48 sys=0.00, real=1.30 secs] 
2020-05-15T12:43:01.786+0000: 557924.953: [CMS-concurrent-abortable-preclean: 1.402/1.491 secs] [Times: user=9.52 sys=0.00, real=1.50 secs] 
2020-05-15T13:44:20.479+0000: 561603.646: [CMS-concurrent-mark: 1.280/1.280 secs] [Times: user=17.49 sys=0.00, real=1.28 secs]
```

Comment: your title has one question, while your post has another. So which one is it? Either way, `CMS` is deprecated.

Comment: Well, I did not mean to confuse, but the question is same, It did pause for 13 seconds. Why is it?

Comment: because it had to. Don't get me wrong, but a GC stops the world because it must do so, because that is how it is supposed to work. CMS isn't a great GC choice, you might wanna switch to better ones.